# Join in nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following entities

```
public class Category 
{
      Id
      Name
}
public class Product 
{
      Id
      Name
      List<Category> list;
}
```

what I want to do is get all the product by category name using nHibernate

any help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for help

i have solved the problem using Join , I didn't fine NHibernate.Linq.dll in the version that I have and I have served the Internet to download it

My Solution is

```
public IList<Product> GetAllProductsByCategoryName(string name)
{
    return Session.CreateQuery("from Product p left join fetch p.Categories c where c.Name = :name").SetParameter("name", name).List<Product>();

}
```

Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way - to use Linq to nhibernate.

Would look like this:

```
public void GetProductsByCategoryName(string categoryName){
  Session.Linq<Product>(x=>x.list.Any(z=>z.Name=categoryName));
}
```